# Continuous functions with the properties $\int^{2}_{-1}x^{2n}f(x)\mathrm dx=0$ or $\int^{2}_{-1}x^{3n}f(x)\mathrm dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis

My question is:

> Show that there exists a nonzero $f \in C[-1,2]$ so that  $$\int^{2}_{-1}x^{2n}f(x)\mathrm dx=0$$
> for all $0\leq n\in \mathbb Z$, but there does not exists a nonzero $f\in C[-1,2]$ such that
> $$\int^{2}_{-1}x^{3n}f(x)\mathrm dx=0$$
> for all $0\leq n \in\mathbb Z$.

I think this question is quite different from $$\int^{1}_{0}x^{n}f(x)\mathrm dx=0$$
because of $x^{2n}$ , $x^{3n}$ and the interval $[-1,2]$. I have been thinking over this for a long time, I know this is related to Stone-Weierstrass theorem but I still have no idea how to solve this. Can anyone please help me with this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You go through the hypotheses of the Stone-Weierstrauss Theorem.  You realize that the functions $x^{2n}$ don't separate points, that is, they don't separate $x$ and $-x$.  Then you realize that any odd function in $C([-1,2])$, supported on $[-1,1]$  provides an example for the first question.

Comment: Hi Stephen! Thank you for your answer. But I am still a little confused. Could you please further explain how this odd function makes the integral =0 by providing an example? I tried f(x)=x but it looks like it does not fit the first question. I just started to learn Stone-Weierstrass and I am still not very good at using it:)

Comment: $f(x) = x$ isn't supported on $[-1,1]$.  Look at the other answer for an explicit example.

Answer (score 2):

Any odd fucntion on $[-1,1]$ vanishing at the end points ($(\sin (\pi z)$ for example) extended to $[-1,2]$ by making it $0$ on $[1,2]$ answers the first question.

For the second question make the change of variable $y=x^{3}$. We get $\int_{-1}^{2^{1/3}} y^{n} g(y)dy=0$ for all $n \geq 0$ where $g(y)=\frac  1 3 y^{-2/3}f(y)$. This implies that $g(y)=0$ and hence $f(y)=0$ for all $y$. Surely $g$ is not continuous but any integrable function on $[a,b]$ with $\int_a^{b} y^{n}g(y)dy=0$ for all $n \geq 0$ vanishes almost everywhere (and $f=0$ almost everywhere implies $f=0$ everywhere by continuity).

Comment: Thank you very much! The example is really helpful!